# Date range overlap issue in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Given date range in Table for particular record say for particular feild "Name"

If some one trying to insert that Name within previous date range interval then it should not be allowed.

I have tried here some code look at this ...

```
if (dataContext.TableAs.Where(
    x => x.EndDate > StartDate &&
    x.Name == Name).Count() == 0)
{
    //insert record
}
```

but is not successful all times.

Can anyone suggest what I have missing over here ?

I have tried below query in SQL , how can I use that in LINQ for above code

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA WHERE ('2012-04-02' between StartDate and EndDate or '2012-08-28' 
between StartDate and EndDate or StartDate between '2012-04-02' and  '2012-08-28' or       EndDatebetween '2012-04-02' and  '2012-08-28' ) and Name='Test'
```

Comment: See my edit for second part of your question

Comment: Can you clarify.  If 2 records exist `Begin=2012-01-01,End=2012-01-31` and `Begin=2012-03-01,End=2012-03-05` is adding `Begin=2012-02-01,End=2012-02-05` allowed?

Comment: yes it allowed , if you are considering Begin=2012-01-05,End=2012-02-05 then it would not be allowed

Comment: In that case you can simplify the between clause to just `'2012-04-02' <= EndDate and '2012-08-28' >=StartDate`. Then see my answer for the appropriate linq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this;

```
if (dataContext.TableAs
            .Where(x => x.Name == Name)
                .Max(x  => x.EndDate) < StartDate)
```

**EDIT - For second part of question**

```
DateTime Date1 = new DateTime("2012-04-02");
DateTime Date2 = new DateTime("2012-08-28");

var query = (dataContext.TableAs
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Test")
            .Where(x => (x.StartDate >= Date1 && Date1 <= x.EndDate)
                    || (x.StartDate >= Date2 && Date2 <= x.EndDate)
                    || (Date1 >= x.StartDate && x.StartDate <= Date2)
                    || (Date1 >= x.EndDate && x.EndDate <= Date2))).Count();
```

Comment: Use `Any` rather than `Count`

Answer (score 0):

```
var StartDate = new DateTime(2012,04,02);
var EndDate = new DateTime(2012,08,28);
var Name = "Test";

if (!dataContext.TableAs.Any(
   x=> x.Name == Name && x.EndDate >= StartDate && x.StartDate <= EndDate
)
{
    //insert record
}
```